# extraer datos de una tabla de BD llamada nota en una session de carrito de compras para su edición

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, session

hola saludos quisiera saber si alguien me podría echar una mano, lo que pasa es que estoy desarrollando una tienda en linea en la cual después de guardar mi carrito de compras en mi bd, haora nacio la necesidad de editar los datos de el carrito que guardo en la bd, he estado intentando estraer los datos de mi tabla nota con un select y vaciarlos  a una session llamada shopping_cart para su posterior edicion de la lista de productos y asi actualizar la bd con los nuevos productos que desea el usuario. este es mi codigo no me carga los productos a la seesion carrito, en que me estoy equivocando saludos espero me ayunden, recibo el codigo de la cotizacion ala cual esta ligada esa nota de productos por el metodo get,

```
<?php
include '../conexion/conexion.php';
$cod_coti=htmlentities($_GET['cod_coti']);
if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
{
  $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "item_id");
  // if(!in_array($_GET["cod_coti"], $item_array_id))
  // {

  $sel=$con->prepare("SELECT*FROM nota WHERE cod_cotizacion1 =? ");
  $sel->bind_param('s',$cod_coti);
  $sel->execute();
  $res=$sel->get_result();
  $row=mysqli_num_rows($res);
    while($f=$res->fetch_assoc()){


    $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
    $item_array = array(
      'item_id'         =>   $f['modelo2'],
      'item_name'           =>  $f['nombrepro'],
      'item_price'      =>  $f['precio'],
      'item_quantity'       => $f['cantidad']
    );
    // $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] = $item_array;

    array_push($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], $item_array);
}
    // asigno valor a variable code= a cero para evitar que recarge la pagina con el valor
  // }


}
 ?>
```

Nota el el archivo :  include '../conexion/conexion.php'; ya contiene el sessionstart este es el codigo en el archivo conexion:

```
 <?php
    @session_start();//  aqui en sesion start se guardaran todas la variables
    $con= new mysqli('localhost','root','123','empresa');
     ?>
```

Comment: Buenas, de primeras te falta poner al principio `session_start()`, después del include.

Comment: Va, no me gusta jugar con los includes y session_start() xDD, pero le ecaré un ojo más a fondo a ver si veo el fallo

Comment: muchas gracias saludos

Comment: Al usas setencias preparadas no necesitas escapar nada, pues la sentencia preparada lo hace. Prueba  a cambiar esto: `$cod_coti=$con->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_GET['cod_coti']));` por esto: `$cod_coti=$_GET['cod_coti'];`. Conviene que también verifiques con `isset($_GET['cod_coti'])...`
.  También, escribe tu consulta así: `SELECT * FROM nota WHERE cod_cotizacion1 =?` y haz un `var_dump($variable);` de tus variables para depurar. Por cierto, el uso de `@` es considerado una mala práctica, porque hace difícil la depuración.

Comment: muchas gracias, por ayudar soy novato estoy en mis practicas y agradesco la ayuda saludos probare el codigo gracias

Comment: Una duda, estos datos se devuelven a un `ajax`?

Comment: no todavía no aprendo ajax estoy en el proceso de aprender,  pero por el momento  solo es por medio de método get que recibo y envio variables entre formularios o a la bd